# Looping through list of data frames and performing operation

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a list of dataframes and I am performing an operation on the list using a for loop. df1, df2, df3 and df4 are data frames.  After the operations, I am not finding the modifications on the dataframe.  Please help me understand what am I missing and why this is not working?

What modifications do I need to make in order to get the changes passed to the source dataframes.

```
sheetnames = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
i=0
for sheet in sheetnames:    
    ixNaNList = sheet[sheet.isnull().all(axis=1) == True].index.tolist()
    if len(ixNaNList) > 0:
        ixNaN = ixNaNList[0]
        sheetnames[i]=sheet[:ixNaN]
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 3):

Your assingment `sheetnames[i] = ...` replaces the i-th element of the list `sheetnames` with whatever `sheet[:ixNaN]` evaluates to.

It thus has no effect on the content of `df1`, `df2`, `df3` or `df4`.

Comment: Could you please help me on how do I modify the df1, df2, df3 or df4 dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sheetnames = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
def drop_after_na(df):
    return df[df.isnull().all(axis=1).astype(int).cumsum() <= 0]
sheetnames = map(drop_after_na, sheetnames)
```

and try this:

```
sheetnames = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df4']
for sheet in sheetnames:
    exec('{sheet} = {sheet}[{sheet}.isnull().all(axis=1).astype(int).cumsum() <= 0]'.format(sheet=sheet))
```

Comment: I am actually dropping all the rows after a null row is hit.  Appreciate your help

Comment: Thanks for the help!  However, although `df[df.isnull().all(axis=1).astype(int).cumsum() <= 0]` removes all the rows after NAs in df, this change is not carried to df1,df2 etc.. using map function.  Interestingly, I could see the required result in sheetnames[i].

Comment: I know what you mean, But I don't think it's good idea to do this kind of code! You should read more python and pandas text and code, and try programing in pythonic way.